# Prerender local version on a VPS with low ram

Tags: nginx, prerender

I have a VPS with 2gb's of ram and a website with 100.000+ pages, a newspaper (wrote on AngularJS). How can i set up prerender (with nginx) to not use more that 300mb of ram? Because it eats all available memory now and my VPS is going to swap memory.

Launching prerender with pm2. How can i tune my prerender?

Comment: You'll want to run Prerender on its own server with enough power. I don't think you can limit it so you won't want to run it on the same server as your website.

Comment: Do you have any docs on using prerender on different server? I am using nginx as middleware.

Comment: We just have our documentation on our website for running locally. The open source Prerender server is set up for deployment on Heroku or Elastic Beanstalk without much configuration.